# Running executable in python without beeing in the same path

Tags: python

I am trying to run a executable from a other direction than my python script. OS and subprocess are not working, even if I enter the path to the .exe. They just run the .exe if they are in the same location.

Comment: Can you provide a short, executable example of code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. The rules for running a python script that uses tkinter is the same for any python script.